# DB, how to select data based on time and particular interval

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database, my program will insert data to that table in every 10 mins.

The table has a field recording the insert date and time.

Now I want to retrieve those data, but I don't want hundreds of data comes out.

I want to get 1 records from every half hour based on insert time stamp (so less than 50 in total of a day).

For that 1 record, it can be either random pick or average from each interval.
Sorry for the ambiguit, cuz I just wanna figure out the way to select from intervals

Let say,

```
Table name: network_speed  
----------------------------------

ID.  .......  Speed   .........     Insert_time

1    .......    10    .........         10:02am......
2    .......    12    .........         10:12am......
...
...
...
123   .......   17     ........        9:23am........
```

To get them all but out put must be average of each half hour record

How can I write a query to achieve this?

Comment: 1 or 2 records... Just any at random? Closest to the end of the hour? Top of the hour? This isn't clear.

Comment: ChicagoRedSox: sorry for the confusion, let just say 1 in every half hour

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (you added both tags). Interval/Date/Time handling is quite different between the two.

Comment: @IvanLi so a completely random result from each half hour?

Comment: MySQL will be great, cuz I'm planning to implement them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that calculates half hour intervals on a specific day ( 2013-09-04).

```
SELECT ID, Speed, Insert_time,
ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-09-04', Insert_time)/48) AS 'interval'
FROM network_speed
WHERE DATE(Insert_time) = '2013-09-04';
```

Use that in a nested query to get stats on the records in the intervals.

```
SELECT IT.interval, COUNT(ID), MIN(Insert_time), MAX(Insert_time), AVG(Speed)
FROM
    (SELECT ID, Speed, Insert_time,
     ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-09-04', Insert_time)/48) AS 'interval'
     FROM network_speed
     WHERE DATE(Insert_time) = '2013-09-04') AS IT
GROUP BY IT.interval;
```

Here it is used to get the first record in each interval.

```
SELECT NS.*
FROM
    (SELECT IT.interval, MIN(ID) AS 'first_id'
     FROM
        (SELECT ID, Speed, Insert_time,
         ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-09-04', Insert_time)/48) AS 'interval'
         FROM network_speed
         WHERE DATE(Insert_time) = '2013-09-04') AS IT
     GROUP BY IT.interval) AS MI,
     network_speed AS NS
WHERE MI.first_id = NS.ID;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
   SELECT HOUR(ts) as hr, fld1, fld2 from tbl group by hr
```

This query selects only hour from the timestamp and then groups the result based on the hour field so you get 1 row for each hour